# VBA to ignore when worksheet is mentioned if it does not exist

Tags: excel, vba

I've been doing some pretty extensive research on trying to find this VBA code for excel, but I'm sure someone on here much smarter than I has an answer!

I have a pretty long code that is automating an invoicing process for someone in my company, and it references 6 different detail tabs.
Sometimes, 3 of these tabs do not exist, because those clients did not invoice this week.

I'm wondering if there is a code that will ignore those worksheets if they do not exist, that I can put at the beginning of the code and have it apply to EVERY time the name is mentioned, rather than having to add code before every single mention of the sheetname throughout my 4-page code.

Comment: Try iterating through the worksheet collection using a For Each loop.

Comment: You could use error handling, put something like `on error goto next_tab` at the beginning of your code where `next_tab` is a Label you defined in your code. If an error occurs, vba will stop the execution, jump to that Label and continue from there on (this obviously only works flawlessly if you don't use error handling right now).

Comment: @JanB the problem with this approach is that GoTo's are a nasty habit, and they can lead to poorly written/hard to fix code.

Comment: @BrandonBarney Usually I'd fully agree, but since it's the only way of handling Errors in vba you can hardly avoid it :(

Comment: @JanB It is most certainly not the only way of handling errors. I have very complex projects which handle almost all errors without GoTo blocks. The best approach is to ensure that the logic is sound beforehand. For example, `Dim Foo as Bar : Debug.Print Foo.Baz` would cause an error since Foo is never set. On the other hand `Dim Foo as Bar : If Not Foo Is Nothing Then Debug.Print Foo.Baz` would run just fine since it checks to see if an error could occur before performing the operation. This approach is far sturdier than the 'On Error GoTo Foo' approach.

Comment: Strong advice for anyone, particularly those who are new to VBA, never accept something as 'The only way'. Three months ago I would've happily said that proper error handling was impossible. I would have also told you that combining data from two arrays would exponentially decrease performance based on the size of the arrays (10x10 & 10x20 would be 10x faster than 100x100 & 100x200) but by challenging the notion that 'That's how VBA is.' i've turned hour long operations into minute long operations. Always develop your abilities if you want to write VBA well.

Comment: @BrandonBarney Of course, you are right, error avoidance should always be considered. I was referring to strict error handling like java's try ... catch. This does not exist in vba; `on error goto` is the closest we get here... :(

In this particular example there is no pre-defined routine to check if a worksheet exists without raising an error if it doesn't (well you could reverse the process and check if all worksheets are not the desired one...) therefore I recommended using this technique.

Comment: @JanB You are correct that there is no try, catch, finally but this doesnt mean there isnt error handling. One could raise custom errors, or use private subs/functions. You could also use a routine to easily check if the worksheet exists (`Dim Foo as Worksheet : On Error Resume Next : Set Foo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bar") : On Error GoTo 0 : If Not Foo Is Nothing Then Debug.Print "Sheet Exists!"` while this uses an `On Error` block, it ultimately handles the error all within the same few lines, and avoids the messy `GoTo` command.

Answer (score 3):

You could check if the worksheet exists first by trying to reference it:

```
Sub Test()

    If WorkSheetExists("Sheet1") Then
        'do stuff
    End If

End Sub

Public Function WorkSheetExists(SheetName As String, Optional WrkBk As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    If WrkBk Is Nothing Then
        Set WrkBk = ThisWorkbook
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
        Set wrkSht = WrkBk.Worksheets(SheetName)
        WorkSheetExists = (Err.Number = 0)
        Set wrkSht = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Another way of writing the code, taking into account what @Brandon posted:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    If WorkSheetExists("Sheet2") Then
        Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    End If

    If Not wrkSht Is Nothing Then
        'Do Stuff
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You may want to explain a bit of why you took this approach so newer users can understand it a bit better. It makes sense by the logic, but not everyone will know why you are using the patterns that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to structure your code in such a way that it allows you to properly and easily check for existence of objects, and then handle the logic as appropriate. Consider the following:

```
Sub Foo()
    If Not Bar Is Nothing Then
        Baz(Bar)
    End If
End Sub
```

This is my most common approach (simplified of course) where I check to ensure that the reverse of the object is nothing, and if so then it uses that object.

If you are unable to take this approach, then the more tedious approach is of course to wrap each reference in an `If` block. While tedious, it is better than using `On Error Resume Next` or `On Error GoTo 0`. Remember the quote "Slow is fast" which is important to remember when writing code. What may be quick fixes now will inevitably cost hours of debugging as your projects get more complicated. It is best not to develop bad habits too soon.